# In powerpoint web app 2013,PPT is not displayed correctly in MAC OS Mozilla Firefox,even working fine in other browsers

Tags: sharepoint-addin, browsers

I have created a PowerPoint app in SharePoint 2013 and I used a ppt in this app.

My ppt images are displaying correctly in Google Chrome and in Internet Explorer in MAC OS, but it is not displaying correctly in Mozilla Firefox in MAC OS.I have already checked possible reasons like:

1. Restarted my computer
2. Clear cookies and cache
3. Restarted Firefox in Safe Mode
4. Troubleshoot all plugins
5. Reinstalled Firefox
6. Reset Firefox

The first image is showing an incorrect display of ppt and the second image is showing the required way to display it. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

[image]

**It must be displayed like this:**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue, Silverlight plugin for Mozilla Firefox will help it out.